# Behavior of docker compose v3's deploy resources limits 'cpus' parameter setting (is it an absolute number or a percentage of available cores)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Folks,

With regards to docker compose v3's [`'cpus'` parameter](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#resources) setting (under `'deploy' 'resources' 'limits'`) to limit the available CPUs to a service, is it an absolute number that specifies the count of CPUs or is it a more useful percentage of available CPUs setting.

From what i read it appears to be an absolute number, where in, say if a host has 4 CPUs and one were to set two services in the compose file with 0.5 then both the services combined can only use a max of 1 CPU (0.5 each) while leaving the 3 remaining CPUs idle.

But thinking loudly it appears to me that it would be nicer if this is a percentage of available cores setting in which case for the same previous example this would result in both services each being able to use up to 2 CPUs each & thereby the two combined could use up all 4 when needed. This way when i increase or decrease the available cores the relative settings would help avoid modifying this value again.

EDIT(09/10/21):

On reading [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-share-constraint) it appears that the above can be achieved with `'cpu-shares'` setting instead of setting `'cpus'`. Is my understanding correct?

The doc for `'cpu-shares'` however mentions the below cautionary note,

> "It does not guarantee or reserve any specific CPU access."

If the above is achieved with this setting, then what does it mean (what is to lose) to not have a guarantee or reservation?

EDIT(09/13/21):

Just to summarize,

- The `'cpus'` parameter setting is an an ***absolute number*** that refers to the number of CPUs a service has **reserved** for it to use ***at all times***. Correct?
- The `'cpu-shares'` parameter setting is a ***relative weight number*** the value of which is ***used to compute/determine the percentage of total available CPU*** that a service can use ***only when there is contention***. Correct?

Comment: also, this setting applies to swarm, not compose.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBecke yes it applies to swarm i know, my question is on the setting attribute behavior in compose v3 for it, which was changed from a more elaborate set of settings in v2..

Comment: One question i have in this area is if one can use 'cpu-shares' setting to achieve the above goal..